# Derivative of the moments of a distribution function

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am wondering if the derivatives of the moment forms of the statistical distributions, as demonstrated below, are always zero. As far as I know, the derivative of a definite integral should be zero, but the derivative of an indefinite integral should give the integrand. In this particular case, a moment consists of a definite integral returning a constant value. Therefore, the derivative of the moment should be zero as well. However, I might still miss some fundamental knowledge here.

$\frac{d}{dx}(\int_0^\infty (x-0)^n f(x) dx)  $

$\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-0)^n f(x) dx) $

I would be glad if you kindly provide some responses to the above question.

Regards,

Comment: Any moment of a distribution, if it exists, is a finite universal constant. Taking its derivative will certainly give you zero. Are you instead trying to connect the derivatives of the moment generating function to the moments of a given distribution?

Comment: No, let me express it more clearly. There is a well-known equation in powder science to convert a number-weighted particle size distribution (fn(x)) to its mass-weighted (fm(x)) particle size distribution by dividing (fn(x)*x^3) to the third moment of fn(x). This equation can be done simply if fn(x) is known. However, to estimate fn(x), you need to count the number of powders, which is very hard. Instead, I am trying find find fn(x) from fm(x). To do that, I have to take derivative of the moment of fn(x) at some point. I just want to be sure that I do the right calculation.